# How to sort the index of a pandas.Dataframe to pass pd.testing.assert_frame_equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pd.testing.assert_frame_equal to test if a function I've written works as expected, and I'm getting a weird error:

When I compare the 2 dataframes that are printed in exactly the same way (I checked the values are the same with np.array_equal(df1.values, df2.values), so I know they're the same by human standards), It gives me an assertion error:

```py
DataFrame.index values are different (90.0 %)
[left]:  Int64Index([0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14,
            17],
           dtype='int64')
[right]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=20, step=1)
```

where left is the dataframe returned by the function and right is the one I created for the testing.

There are 2 errors here. First, the types of the indexes are not equal, which is weird, but can be solved easily by doing :

```py
right.index = list(right.index)
```

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52576441/21404794). The second problem is the order of the left indexes, as after adding that line of code to the test it still returns this error:

```py
DataFrame.index values are different (90.0 %)
[left]:  Int64Index([0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14,
            17],
           dtype='int64')
[right]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
            19],
           dtype='int64')
```

The function I'm testing splits the dataframe in groups, [melts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) some of them, and then [joins](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) everything back together.

I'm using [sort_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_index) inside the function to keep the indexes ordered (as they should be), but while in the prints I've done they appear ordered (0,1,2,3...) in the testing error, as you can see they are not ordered.

I've also tried using reindex and reset_index, but they didn't show any difference (maybe there's some hidden option I've not tried out, who knows...

The final question is: How can I order the Indexes of a DataFrame so the testing can pass?

**When used in the correct file and function, sort_index allows the test to pass**

(I was changing a copy instead of the correct function...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue on pandas 2.0.0+

```
print(pd.__version__)
# 2.0.1

idx1 = pd.Index([0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17], dtype='int64')
idx2 = pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=20, step=1)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=idx1).sort_index()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=idx2)

print(df1.index)
# Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], dtype='int64')
print(df2.index)
# RangeIndex(start=0, stop=20, step=1)

pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2) # no error
```

Comment: I'm stupid, I was doing changes in a copy of the function I had, I think the problem is solved now, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you use sort_index correctly in the function you're testing, it passes.

If you modify other function in other file, you're not improving the function you're testing, so it won't pass